# How can add filter to my cells, in google sheets ?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have no idea about javascript... I don't know how to deal with google spreadsheet either. My problem is, we have a tracking system on our club. The system is if you miss 3 days in a month you will be removed from the tracking system for that month. We have the names on another page, so the cell is taking the names from that column -> image

[image]
Taking From this name column

[image]
And displaying here, and we are being able to choose our name to enter data.

Now my question is, when someone passed 3 hours (Missed column at the first image), how can we arrange it so that in the second sheet it will not display their name (Because they will be out so they shouldn't enter any data)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any google-apps-script for that, you can just add a control sheet.

In `A1` you put:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A, Sheet1!F2:F < 3)
```

And for the data validation in Sheet2 you use the range `Control!A1:A`